# Why is some of my image grid showing up empty spaces?

Tags: css, flexbox

There are some blank areas in my grid and I'm not sure why that's happening. I've tried to make the number of images in each column equal, also tried to have the columns alternating.

```html
.column img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 0 4px;

}

.column {
    flex: 50%;
    max-width: 50%;

}
```

Comment: Add your HTML please.

Comment: Can't see your code

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example